# can I say: I have go to school as far as zoo

Tags: prepositions, time

My route is: home → zoo → school.

I go to school from my home. I am at zoo now.

can I say: I have go to school as far as zoo.

Comment: "I am on the way to school, and have gotten as far as the zoo."

Answer (score 1):

You can say,

> "I go to school by way of the zoo, which is where I am now."

You can also say,

> "My route to school takes me by the zoo, which is where I am now."

Or,

> "The zoo is on my way to school, so I have stopped there for awhile."

Or, as @TRomano suggested in his comment,

> "I am on the way to school, and have gotten as far as the zoo."

Comment: Or, sticking as close to the O.P.'s original words as I can muster: _I have to go to school; I'm as far as the zoo._ (That's grammatical, even though yours sound more natural.)